# How did macro-instructions and indirect addressing interact in IBM's MAP/FAP assemblers?

Tags: assembly, programming

The MAP and FAP assemblers for the IBM 709/7090/7094 had a nice macro facility. I was surprised by its power. (Actually, I guess it is possible that most macro processors at the time were as sophisticated, but I haven't seen any. Strachey's “[General-purpose macro-generator](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/8/3/225/336044)”, from a year later, was incredibly limited by comparison) Here are some of its capabilities:

- Macros could have an arbitrary number of parameters.
- Macro expansions could nest.
- Macro *definitions* could nest (macro-defining macros were possible).
- With the `IFF` and `IFT` pseudo-instructions (only `IFF` in FAP) text could be substituted conditionally.
- The `IRP` pseudo-instruction allowed iterating over a comma-separated list.
- The `SET` pseudo-instruction changed the value of a symbol. By combining `SET` with the macro-related pseudo-instructions, you can implement arbitrary loops; `SET` also makes recursive macro expansion more useful.
- The `GOTO` pseudo-instruction (only in MAP) made it possible to instruct the assembler not to include a certain number of instructions in the expansion.
- Concatenation of arguments and other text could be done, with the `'` character.

Here is all the relevant documentation I have been able to locate:

- [C28-6235-3 FAP (1965)](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/7090/C28-6235-3_FAP_Apr64.pdf)
- [C28-6235-5 FAP (1965)](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/7090/C28-6235-5_FAP_Apr65.pdf)
- [C28-6311-2 MAP (1964)](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/7090/C28-6311-2_7090_MAP.pdf)
- [C28-6311-4 MAP (1964)](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/7090/C28-6311-4_MAP_Oct64.pdf)
- [C28-6392-0 MAP (1963)](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/7090/C28-6392-0_v13_MAP.pdf)
- [C28-6392-1 MAP (1965)](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/7090/C28-6392-1_v13_MAP_Jul65.pdf)
- [C28-6392-4 MAP (1966)](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/7090/C28-6392-4_MAP_Dec66.pdf)
- [GC28-6392-4 MAP (1966)](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/7090/C28-6392-4_MAP_Dec66.pdf)
- [CTSS Programmer's Guide (1969), section AH.2.07](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/mit/ctss/CTSS_ProgrammersGuide_Dec69.pdf#page=306)

There is earlier information about FAP, but from before it had support for macros.

---

The general form of a macro definition in FAP was this:

```
NAME   MACRO   P1,P2,P3
       ...
NAME   END
```

Here `NAME` is the name of the macro, `P1`, `P2`, and `P3` are parameters, and the text elided with “`...`” is the macro's body. After such a definition, you can use `NAME` as if it were any other instruction, as in

```
       NAME    X,Y,Z
```

In the body, occurrences of `P1`, `P2`, `P3` would be replaced with the corresponding arguments (in the example, `X`, `Y`, and `Z`).

If a macro-instruction includes a symbol in its location/name field, as in

```
ABCDEF NAME    X,Y,Z
```

then the effect would be as if the symbol had been given with the first instruction of the macro expansion. For example, if the macro's body began like this:

```
NAME   MACRO   P1,P2,P3
       CLA     LOCAT,4
       ...
NAME   END
```

then the expansion of

```
ABCDEF NAME    X,Y,Z
```

would begin

```
ABCDEF CLA     LOCAT,4
```

An alternative form of macro definition could change this behavior. If you wrote

```
        MACRO
SYMPAR  NAME   P1,P2,P3
        ...
NAME    END
```

then the macro would essentially gain a new parameter, here named `SYMPAR`, which would be matched to a symbol given in the location field of a use of the macro. Thus in the expansion of

```
ABCDEF NAME    X,Y,Z
```

any occurrences of `SYMPAR` would be replaced by `ABCDEF`. (This alternative form works in MAP, but it is not documented in any of the MAP manuals listed above.)

---

The IBM 709/7090/7094 support indirect addressing, indicated in assembly code by placing an asterisk after the operation mnemonic. So the instruction

```
       STA*    LOC
```

Replaces the address part of the accumulator with the value stored at the address stored in `LOC`.
What happens if a macro-instruction includes the indirection tag? For instance, what would happen if I said

```
       NAME*   X,Y,Z
```

---

For an incredible demonstration of the assembler's abilities, see this code from 1966, which expresses preloaded list structure in a Lisp interpreter by using macros: https://github.com/rcornwell/ctss/blob/master/extra/lisp/atoms.fap.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the /360 ASSEMBF as that macro language is a follow up with a more regular structure, dropping all machine specific parts in favour for a more regular structure.

Comment: @Raffzahn, do you happen to have any links to the ASSEMBF documentation? I tried to Google for it, but failed to find even a single mention of it.

Comment: @introspec ASSEMBF is essential the [basic IBM Assembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Basic_Assembly_Language_and_successors) for machines with more than  64 KiB offering all functionality. Today's offspring is IBM's [HLASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_High_Level_Assembler) - but, except for new addressing modes not much has changes - the high level macros are backward compatible (although I usually preferred my own set, based on a late 1970 implementation for structured programming :)) Also, ASSEMBF is, IIRC, open source. (Links to manuals in linked Wiki articles)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not documented anywhere, as far as I can tell. But the source code of a few versions of the assemblers is available, so we can look there.

It turns out that there is a third form of macro definition. If you say `MACRO*` instead of `MACRO`, then the contents of the first parameter of your macro will be `*` if the macro was invoked with an asterisk, and empty otherwise. So

```
DOIT   MACRO* I,D,S,IR
       SXA    S,IR
       TSX'I  D,IR
DOIT   END
```

would define a (useless) macro that carried an indirection flag to the `TSX`. When invoked as

```
       DOIT   PLACE1,PLACE2,4
```

the expansion is

```
       SXA    PLACE2,4
       TSX    PLACE1,4
```

but if invoked as

```
       DOIT*  PLACE1,PLACE2,4
```

the expansion is

```
       SXA    PLACE2,4
       TSX*   PLACE1,4
```

Here is an excerpt from MAP's source code. (You can find it as 7090-SP-804 IBMAP [here](http://sky-visions.com/ibm/ibsys_tapes.shtml); append `.gz` to the printable ASCII tape links to get them to work.)

```
* THE INTERNAL DICTIONARY ENTRY FOR A MACRO-INSTRUCTION HAS THE FORM (6)4J161702
*                                                                    (6)4J161704
*              O6/62,12/N,3/SC,15/SKEL                               (6)4J161706
*                                                                    (6)4J161708
*      WHERE                                                         (6)4J161710
*                                                                    (6)4J161712
*              N IS THE NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS                          (6)4J161714
*                                                                    (6)4J161715
*              SC IS 2 TO SUPPRESS CREATED SYMBOLS FOR MISSING ARGS  (6)4J161716
*                    6 TO FORCE CREATION OF MISSING ARG SYMBOLS      (6)4J161718
*                    0 FOR SYMBOL CREATION UNDER NOCRS CONTROL       (6)4J161720
*                                                                    (6)4J161722
*              SKEL IS THE ADDRESS OF THE CHAIN WORD PRECEDING THE   (6)4J161724
*                   SKELETON FOR THE CORRESPONDING MACRO DEFINITION  (6)4J161726
*                                                                    (6)4J161728
* EACH SKELETON IS PRECEDED BY A CHAIN WORD WHOSE                    (6)4J161730
*                                                                    (6)4J161732
*              ADDRESS IS A POINTER TO THE CHAIN WORD FOR THE NEXT   (6)4J161734
*                   SKELETON (OR END OF DEFINITION STORAGE IF LAST)  (6)4J161736
*                                                                    (6)4J161738
*              DECREMENT IS A POINTER TO THE DICTIONARY ENTRY        (6)4J161740
*                                                                    (6)4J161742
*              PREFIX HAS FLAGS FOR PURGE AS FOLLOWS..               (6)4J161744
*                                                                    (6)4J161746
*                   S - SKELETON IS TO BE PURGED FROM TABLE          (6)4J161748
*                   1 - CANNOT BE PURGED BECAUSE OTHER DEFINITIONS   (6)4J161750
*                       REFER TO THIS ONE VIA OPSYN                  (6)4J161752
*                   2 - CONTAINS ADDRESS POINTERS FOR OPSYN          (6)4J161754
*                                                                    (6)4J161756
* THE TAG FIELD OF THE CHAIN WORD SUPPLEMENTS THE DICTIONARY ENTRY   (6)4J161758
*      WITH FLAGS FOR                                                (6)4J161759
*                                                                    (6)4J161760
*              LOCATION FIELD OF MACRO IS A PARAMETER (BIT 18).      (6)4J161762
*                                                                    (6)4J161763
*              NAME OF MACRO-INSTRUCTION IS A PARAMETER (BIT 19).    (6)4J161764
*                                                                    (6)4J161765
*              THE USE OF INDIRECT ADDRESSING OF THIS MACRO IS A     (6)4J161766
*                   PARAMETER (BIT 20 OF CHAIN WORD).  THE ARGUMENT  (6)4J161768
*                   WHICH WAS FIRST IN THE VARIABLE FIELD OF THE     (6)4J161770
*                   MACRO HEADER WILL BE REPLACED IN THE EXPANSION   (6)4J161772
*                   BY THE NULL STRING OR BY AN * ACCORDING TO THE   (6)4J161774
*                   ABSENCE OR PRESENCE OF AN ASTERISK TERMINATING   (6)4J161776
*                   THE OPERATION CODE IN THE CALL.  THE FIRST FIELD (6)4J161778
*                   OF THE VARIABLE FIELD OF THE CALL CORRESPONDS TO (6)4J161780
*                   THE SECOND PARAMETER IN THE VARIABLE FIELD OF    (6)4J161782
*                   THE MACRO HEADER CARD, ETC.                      (6)4J161784
```

The last point, about bit 20, is the relevant portion. Here “skeleton” is referring to the macro's replacement text.

I haven't yet found any code that actually uses this feature, except for some built-in internal macros to the MAP assembler (see, e.g., card 4J198700).

(I'm not sure whether the feature was implemented in FAP or not. A [location `MCDIND` is reserved](https://github.com/rcornwell/ctss/blob/master/src/tools/fap.fap#L6623) for a “FLAG FOR INDIRECTLY ADDRESSED MACRO”, but the code doesn't seem to do anything with it besides stack and unstack it as macro depth changes. I could certainly be wrong.)

---

What happens if you use the asterisk on a macro not defined with `MACRO*`? It's an error.

```
MCC.22 RNT     100000              IS INDIRECT ADDRESS AN ARGUMENT   (6)4J119300
       TRA     MCC.23              NO, CHECK FOR MISUSED *           (6)4J119400
       CLA     INDPAR              YES, PREPARE TO STUFF *           (6)4J119410
       ZET     SWIND               WAS OP CODE STARRED               (6)4J119420
       ACL     1DECR               YES, ARG HAS LENGTH ONE           (6)4J119430
       TSX     XPLCE,4             PLACE PARAMETER                   (6)4J119440
       TXL     MCC.24,2,0          CHECK FOR MORE ARGUMENTS          (6)4J119450
       TXI     MCC.24,2,-1                                           (6)4J119460
       SPACE                                                         (6)4J119470
MCC.23 ZET     SWIND               WAS OP CODE STARRED               (6)4J119480
       TSX     INDXB,4             YES, FILE ERROR MESSAGE           (6)4J119490
       SPACE   1                                                        4J119500
```

The transfer to `INDXB` causes the message `INDIRECT ADDRESS NOT ALLOWED ON THIS INSTRUCTION` to be printed (eventually).